# Customize starting id in SQL Server auto-increment column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, auto-increment

I have to start my auto-increment column of my table in SQL Server from 1000. In default it starts from 1. Now I have to customize that.

Is that possible??

Comment: Yes, Just Set `Identity Seed` to 1000

Comment: For a next time, please **FIRST** consult the freely available [SQL Server Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545450.aspx) documentation - it's really ease to use, and it contains a **wealth** of information. Under [`IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) you could have **very easily found** your answer ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in create table the syntax is

`column_name data_type identity(startingValue(seed), increment)`

so that in your case it's

`create table table_name ( id int identity(1000 , 1) )`